# Where are apple quicktime trailers stored?

Tags: quicktime

I am watching some quicktime apple trailers from the website they open up automatically in quicktime. How do I download it at that point. I am assuming that they are cached temporally somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure the cache is located in `~/Library/Caches/Quicktime` Then the actual files are distributed in random folders (from 01, 02, 03, etc.).

Comment: Aren't trailers copyrighted material?

Comment: @Richard, no they aren't since you can download them directly with a single click.

Comment: Thanks Michiel I've never downloaded them. My question remains, downloading for ease of personal viewing is one thing but I'm wondering if Apple/studios will mind if the videos get re-posted on other sites. Just because they're downloadable doesn't mean they're not copyrighted material with conditions for re-use. I don't know either way, just pointing out that not everything that's easily downloadable ought to be redistributed so quickly.

Comment: @Richard, I think the trailers are marked with the copyright disclaimer, so I guess you are free to use them... (but that's just a guess)

Comment: "Can download them" does not mean "not copyrighted" nor does it mean "you are free to use them".  Personally I would generally not post them on other sites, but post the link instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can download them directly from the website you know? Just hold down the button for a little longer and then you can select your download format!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `lsof`

This will list all of the files opened by all of your processes.  The process playing the movie will either be Safari or QuickTimeHelper.  The move file will be one of the last ones listed for that process and will have a large size.  It will probably be in a "/tmp/" folder.

When you think you've found the right file, you can verify that it is a quicktime move by typing `file "pathname"` where pathname is the file path given in `lsof`.  Assuming its actually a move file, you can then copy it by doing `cp "pathname" ~/Desktop/mymovie.mov`

There are a number of variations of the above instructions, depending on the type of file and what is actually playing it, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://savedeo.com which allows you to download the videos directly. No additional plugins or software is required.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be using [KeepAndPlay.com](http://keepandplay.com)!

1. Go to [Apple's trailer site](http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/)
2. Find the trailer you would like to download and copy the URL of the trailer
3. Go to [KeepAndPlay.com](http://keepandplay.com)
4. Paste the trailer on the search field (the one with the big red "Download" button)

What is also cool from KeepAndPlay is that you can download videos or just the audio in HD from youtube, Facebook, instagram, vimeo, soundcloud... and many other sites

Here is an example for the trailer The Revenant

[image]